# SQLite gives different result for same query

Tags: sqlite, perl

I have a local (macos) web-based SQLite database with some UTF8 characters in a column. The CLI 'sqlite3' renders them all properly when a query is executed in Terminal. But when the same query is executed via a browser via my local web server (running Perl), I get proper rendering in one query, but mangled rendering in another. The only difference I can find is in the ORDER BY clause. But I'm not clear why that would make a difference. And of course I would to solve the issue and get correct UTF8 rendering. As far as I can tell the data in the database is UTF-8. Any advice suggestions?

Comment: Do you do any encoding/decoding of the data anywhere? Could we see a MWE? In particular, do you set sqlite_unicode when you connect to the database?

Comment: No, no encoding. I am starting from scratch to see what is needed but this is throwing a wrench in. The data is entered via DB Browser or sometimes via a Perl script which I run to add new records. And forgive me, what is MWE?

Comment: MWE=minimal working example, see also [mcve]. I think the problem is that one query returns non-ASCII characters, and you're running into problems because the default encoding for web pages is Latin-1 or something similarly weird. Does putting a `<meta charset="utf-8">` into your HTML fix this?

Comment: Ah. Yes I do have that meta tag in my code. But the way I call the queries is via AJAX - one script orders one column and another script orders by a different column. I will check what my connection is in both scripts.

Comment: I've added 'sqlite_unicode=>1' to the connection string in all the scripts and that seems to be the solution. Thank you very much for your time and expertise.

Comment: I turned my comment into an answer. Though in the future you really should include runnable code so we don't have to guess at the issue.

Comment: Thank for the heads up. I was going to add some code, but tried the insertion first. When it worked, I figured adding code might be redundant.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure, but you may have forgotten to do encoding/decoding on the perl side. To have the DBD take care of that for you, you should pass `sqlite_unicode => 1` in your connection options.